# MvxImageView DefaultImagePath Memory Issue

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin, mvvmcross

In my Xamarin.Android project I use default image path to show a placeholder image while the real image is loaded from a url. This image view is inside a listview;

```
<MvxImageView
   android:layout_width="75dp"
   android:layout_height="75dp"
   local:MvxBind="ImageUrl SenderPicture;
   DefaultImagePath 'res:loading'"
   android:id="@+id/imgProfPic"
   android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

However, this placeholder image is allocated too many times and causes a huge memory issue on lollipop devices.

[image]

That allocation you see that's around 130 - 140 is the loading image which is ten times more than the actual MvxImageView number on my page This is disposed sometimes but it's very inconsistent and often it leads to an out of memory error before it disposes.

This issue does not occur on API levels lower than lollipop.

Are there any workarounds or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: most likely related to deprecation of InPurgeable attribute of BitmapFactory.Options - since Lollipop this flag is ignored, thus the array backing up the image's array cant be reused

Answer (score 0):

Try setting default image as source in MvxImageView.
e.g.: `android:src="@drawable/loading"`
then mvx binding would just update it with downloaded image.

P.S. does this problem occur on every lollopop device?

Keep in note that Nexus devices had memory leak on android 5.0.X

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work unfortunately, and yes it occurs on 5.1.x as well on my samsung device.